# QGIS Generating Lat/Long Degree Grid in Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I made a map in WGS84, which is positioned and referenced correctly.

Now I loaded the map into the Composer and added a grid, with horizontal and vertical lines each 500 world units (m).

When I activate "Draw coordinates" and set them to Degree, it shows absoluteley weird coordinates, like first vertical line 120° E, second line 90° W, third line 160° E and so on, although the coordinates should be something like 120°1'0", 120°1'1" 120°1'2" etc.

Also, the grid does not change if I set its CRS to WGS84, and it does not change, if I change the scale of the map, which I added to the composer.

Can someone can help me?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want a grid with 500 m spacing but it should be labeled in degrees?

Comment: Hello, yes - the grid spacing should be 500m (by the measurments of my map) and the label of each line should show the latitude/longitude of its position on my map.

So for example, if a line of a grid is cuts through a house on my map which has the coordinate 45°4'5" E, the label should show this coordinate.

(The statusbar of QGIS Desktop shows the correct lat/long values in degree...)

PS: It does not need to be 500m, but my map has extends like 5000m by 5000m, and I think 10 lines should be enough to reference places if your walking with a GPS device

Comment: PS: And it should not be part of my map, it should be created in composer,..it has those nice checker board pattern frame...

Answer (score -1):

I made the grid in Qgis composer, and added the coordinate labels by hand in Photoshop - meaning I had to measure the lat/long position of each line by hand in Qgis Desktop.

Comment: I thnk it's just designed for what you want to do. Normally a map will have a regularly space graticule (of latitude-longitude values) or a grid (of projected values). A graticule is defined in degrees-minutes-seconds so that the spacing is every 5 minutes or 2 degrees, etc. 500 m means variable spacing and on-the-fly calculations to locate the lines.

Comment: thats absoluteley correct. A minutes grid would be perfect because it makes locating your position way more predictable.
But it doesn't let me set the interval to degree or minutes.